# DELETE FROM returns 1064 SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't figure out why my request doesn't work. I want to delete the hotspots in the table hotspot and the laptop that uses these hotspots in the table laptop. given a user ID = 2EA81
here it is :

```
DELETE FROM hotspot, laptop WHERE hotspot.user_id= '2EA81' and laptop.id= hotspot.hotspot_ID
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE hotspot.user_id= '2EA81' and laptop.id= ' at line 1

Any idea ?

Comment: What is the full error? The multi-table delete syntax requires you specify after the `DELETE` keyword which table you want to delete from (like `DELETE hotspot FROM hotspot JOIN laptop...)`, and also may not support an implicit inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's [multi-table `DELETE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) expects that you list the tables where rows should actually be deleted to be listed just after the `DELETE` keyword - it will not automatically delete from *all* joined tables.

If you wish to delete rows from both `hotspots` and `laptop`, you'll need to list them after `DELETE`. I would also recommend changing your join expression to an explicit `INNER JOIN`, as described in the [`table_references` section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) of the linked documentation. MySQL should support an implicit (comma-separated `FROM` as you attempted) in a multi-table delete - I have not tested, but the explicit `INNER JOIN` is preferred anyway as a modern syntax.

```
DELETE
  -- list tables to actually delete rows from
  hotspot,
  laptop
FROM
  -- Supply an explicit INNER JOIN
  hotspot
  INNER JOIN laptop ON laptop.id= hotspot.hotspot_ID
WHERE 
  -- Filter rows on conditions
  hotspot.user_id= '2EA81'
```

Listing the tables to delete differs from the single table `DELETE` syntax, where you needn't name any tables between `DELETE` and `FROM` because the single table in the `FROM` clause is implicit as your deletion target.